# Bluetooth two serial ports incoming connections

Tags: java, android, c++, bluetooth, serial-port

I have bluetooth in my laptop. I can assign an incoming port say 6. I have PC app which listens on Port 6. Then I can connect my android device with this and I can send data from android to PC.

Now on PC side, I can assign more than one incoming port to Bluetooth. I can open multiple instances of my app each connecting to a different Port.

The problem is on android side? On android side when we connect we can't specify the port we are going to connect to, we just specify the paired computer. So, only first android device connects. The next one shows up a connection error?

Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use COM ports. Yuk! :-)

Instead use Sockets or a Bluetooth API, then you can accept lots and lots of connections to the same Bluetooth 'server'.  For instance my library [32feet.NET](http://32feet.codeplex.com/).

See e.g. [32feet.NET docs -- Bluetooth%20Server-side](http://32feet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Bluetooth%20Server-side)

However. If you mean one client device (eg Android here) connecting to one server device then there is a restriction. With RFComm, as used by SPP, there can be only one connection from one device to the same server application. To get two connections between two device then there will need to be two RFComm/SPP servers running.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think I'll try brainstorm on this. Just to clarify, I have two PC apps. For Bluetooth I have opened two incoming serial ports. Started the PC apps, on different ports. Fine. Now one android app (Which ever connects first) gets the Bluetooth connection. The Second android app gets connection error?

Comment: Added an answer with a bit more details at the bottom. Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your android device is connecting as *Client*. In Bluetooth RFComm a client can only establish one connection.

To make your android connect to more than one PC you have to make it the server.

take a look at android's Bluetooth Chat example : [Bluetooth Chat Sample](http://jayxie.com/mirrors/android-sdk/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html)

at the end I can't think of a way to allow multiple connections on both ends simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Just to clarify, I have two PC apps. For Bluetooth I have opened two incoming serial ports. Started the PC apps. Fine. Now on one android app (Which ever connects first) get the Bluetooth connection. The Second android app gets connection error?

Comment: To have your android connect to more than client you need to make it listen to connections, not the other way around.
But by doing so you will not be able to have more than one connection from your PC because it became client.
RFFCom Client: only can connect to one server
Server: can connect to many clients

Answer (score 0):

@alanjmcf Thanks.

http://inthehand.com/forums/p/5488/13867.aspx

Used SdpBrowserDesktop app.

Go to Server Tab.

Select Serial Port.

Click on Listen Button.

Start Server instances on PC as many as COM ports (I tried two instance and had Two COM ports)

Now connect you android apps.
One by one.
That's it.

Comment: used http://32feet.codeplex.com  Library.
SdpBrowserDesktop app is included in samples.